# How to calculate the shortest route between a start coordinate and multiple destination coordinates

Tags: here-api

I'm working on my graduation thesis in Computer Science. I'm developing an application that locates the shortest route to some emergency services in the city where I live. I need to know if through the HERE API I can find the shortest route given a start point and VARIOUS destination points, basically, which of these destination points is the closest.

I know I can find the shortest route between a starting point and a destination point, but what about multiple destination possibilities? Would I have to make multiple requests?

```
So far I haven't found how to do this, other than making multiple requests for each target point I have.
```

Example: Given the user's location, there are 5 emergency services on the map, I need to know which of these 5 emergency services is closest and calculate the route to the closest one.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [travelling salesman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) use case.

You do not tell what platform you are using, but for the HERE SDK, multiple stopover `Waypoint` items along a `Route` can be ordered automatically by setting `RouteOptions.optimizeWaypointsOrder`. If set to `true`, the `OfflineRoutingEngine` will try to optimize the waypoints order to reach the destination faster *or* to make the route shorter - this depends on the desired setting in the provided `RouteOptions`.